# How to get the masked user created object id in the master database?

Tags: sql-server

I'm doing some testing with SQL Server and I found that you can create an object in the `master` database that have the same name as a system object. For example, I can create my own `sp_msforeachdb`:

```
USE master;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_msforeachdb AS SELECT 'test';
GO
```

But after that, I can't get the object id of my custom `sp_msforeachdb`. All the following queries give the result `-835749359`, which is the object id of the built in sp_msforeachdb`.

```
SELECT OBJECT_ID('sp_msforeachdb');
SELECT OBJECT_ID('dbo.sp_msforeachdb');
SELECT OBJECT_ID('master.dbo.sp_msforeachdb');
```

In this case, how can I get the object if my version of `sp_msforeachdb`?

Btw, I'm not really replacing `sp_msforeachdb`. I'm just doing some random testing.

Comment: _" I found that you can create an object in the `master` database "_ - yeah, **don't**.

Comment: What happens if you do `select * from master.sys.procedures;` - do you see _your_ `sp_msforeachdb` listed?

Comment: `SELECT OBJECT_ID('master.dbo.sp_msforeachdb');` <-- This **should** work given that the (undocumented) `sp_msforeachdb` exists in the `sys` schema, not the `dbo` schema. Curious...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would not create user objects in the Master database. Even if you do, please do not use the same name ( I know it is a different schema).
To see both objects use this TSQL statement:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM sys.all_objects
WHERE NAME ='sp_msforeachdb'
```